# Redirect to homepage in sharepoint list 2007 or 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am migrating MOSS 2007 portal to sharepoint 2010 without UI upgrade. In MOSS 2007 on feedback form submission "OK" button it redirects to home page. After I migrated to 2010 after the feedback submission it redirects to "sitename/lists/Feedback" and hence throws page not found error. In 2007 I checked all aspx pages related to feedback, no javascript is written, it is all OOTB. I am not understanding what was done in 2007 for this redirection. Also in addition no views are present in view section. But AllItems.aspx exists and i have a navigation link for the same. Please if any1 can guide me in how do i solve this problem in 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if below technique that I used is recomended  but this solved my problem. My Feedback link was menioned in footer in my master page and I appended ?Source=default.aspx in the href of the anchor tag.
e.g.

```
 <a href=/Lists/Feedback/Allitems.aspx?Source=default.aspx>
```